# socket does not connect with server but working on localhost

Tags: ios, swift, websocket

Hi I am trying to connect with live server but cannot connect with live server. but its working fine on localhost.
This is my code

```
 class SocketIOManager: NSObject
    {
        var Delegate:SocketIOManagerDelegate?
        var notificationmode : NSString = NSString()
        static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()
        var iSSocketDisconnected:Bool=Bool()
        var iSChatSocketDisconnected:Bool=Bool()
        var orderId:String = String()
        static var constant_class:Constant=Constant()
        static var theme:Themes=Themes()
        var audioPlayer :AVAudioPlayer!

        var nick_name:NSString=NSString()

        let commonUtlity : Utilities = Utilities();

        var Appdel=UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

        let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: constant_class.SocketCreateRoomUrl as String)!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .forcePolling(true), .reconnects(true), .reconnectAttempts(-1), .secure(false), .forceWebsockets(true)])

        var socket:SocketIOClient!

        override init()
        {

            socket = manager.defaultSocket
            socket = manager.socket(forNamespace: "/chat")        
            super.init()
        }

        func establishConnection(Nickname:NSString)
        {
            if(socket != nil)
            {
                if(socket.status == .disconnected || socket.status == .notConnected)
                {
                    socket.removeAllHandlers()
                    addListeners(Nickname:Nickname)
                    socket.connect()
                }
            }
        }

        func addListeners(Nickname:NSString) {
            ListensocketEvents(Nickname:Nickname)
            ListenUserCreated()
            Litentochat(Nickname:Nickname)
        }
```

This is my logs

```
2020-01-08 09:01:33.719888+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketManager: Trying to reconnect
2020-01-08 09:01:33.720393+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [-7]
2020-01-08 09:01:33.720664+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/chat}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [-7]
2020-01-08 09:01:33.721133+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketManager: Scheduling reconnect in 30.0s
2020-01-08 09:01:33.721579+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:688440] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: ws://deliverydom.pl
2020-01-08 09:01:33.721881+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:688440] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2020-01-08 09:01:34.593543+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:688440] ERROR SocketEngine: Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=400, type=upgradeError
2020-01-08 09:01:34.593589+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["access-control-allow-origin": "ws", "server": "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)", "x-cache": "MISS from localhost", "date": "Wed, 08 Jan 2020 08", "connection": "keep-alive", "access-control-allow-credentials": "true", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "content-type": "application/json"]]
2020-01-08 09:01:34.594140+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/chat}: Handling event: websocketUpgrade with data: [["access-control-allow-origin": "ws", "server": "Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)", "x-cache": "MISS from localhost", "date": "Wed, 08 Jan 2020 08", "connection": "keep-alive", "access-control-allow-credentials": "true", "transfer-encoding": "chunked", "content-type": "application/json"]]
2020-01-08 09:01:34.594586+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] ERROR SocketManager: Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=400, type=upgradeError
2020-01-08 09:01:34.594850+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=400, type=upgradeError"]
2020-01-08 09:01:34.595108+0100 DeliveryDom Driver[2386:686588] LOG SocketIOClient{/chat}: Handling event: error with data: ["Invalid HTTP upgrade. code=400, type=upgradeError"]
```

I also mentioned into info.Plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

It's working fine in android
I also check on mobile data 
I also check like this "ws://liveurl.com/" or  "http://liveurl.com/"

Comment: did you try `wss` ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini yes tried

Comment: Try this for the SocketManager config `[.forceNew(true), .forceWebsockets(true), .log(false)]`